# custom Key board for edit view

Tags: android

i want to make custom key board for edit view Control .when user select edit view control then only allow number,Colon and Dots only character keyboard.How we can develop or any code

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Setup a [inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Searchable%5FinputType) on your EditText

```
<EditText android:inputType="numberDecimal"  />
```

A regex should be something like this:

```
if(myString.matches('0[1-9]:[0-5][0-9]')){
   //String is valid
}
```

Comment: It is very hard to fully customize a keyboard. Why would you want to ':'?

Comment: can you write the Regex expression for android ,i want this HH:MM but First H is 0 and Second ,it has range 1-9 then must be colon : the MM should be 0-59.